# Problema no caption do FusionCharts

Tags: javascript, html, xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um projeto que utiliza a ferramenta FusionCharts (Versão 3.2.1). Preciso gerar um gráfico, mas independente do titulo (caption) que eu utilizo, ele sempre corta, e substitui com a sequencia "...". Ja tentei de tudo, só nao sei se isso é um problema de versao. Inclusive ja tentei conversar com a equipe FusionCharts no forum deles, mas ninguem me ajudou.

Esse é meu javaScript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Multi Series Column 2D Chart</title>
        <link href="../../Contents/assets/ui/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../../Contents/assets/prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script language="JavaScript" src="../../Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Contents/assets/ui/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Contents/assets/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Contents/assets/ui/js/json2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready ( function () {
                $("a.view-chart-data").click( function () {
                    var chartDATA = '';
                    if ($(this).children("span").html() == "View XML" ) {
                        chartDATA = FusionCharts('ChartId').getChartData('xml').replace(/\</gi, "&lt;").replace(/\>/gi, "&gt;");
                    } else if ($(this).children("span").html() == "View JSON") {
                        chartDATA = JSON.stringify( FusionCharts('ChartId').getChartData('json') ,null, 2);
                    }
                    $('pre.prettyprint').html( chartDATA );
                    $('.show-code-block').css('height', ($(document).height() - 56) ).show();
                    prettyPrint();
                })

                $('.show-code-close-btn a').click(function() {
                    $('.show-code-block').hide();
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <h3 class="chart-title">Multi Series Column 2D Chart</h3>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>


        <div id="chartdiv" align="center"> FusionCharts. </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart = new FusionCharts("../../Charts/MSColumn2D.swf", "ChartId", "1024", "300", "0", "0");
            chart.setXMLUrl("../Data/XML/Chart06COR.xml");
            chart.render("chartdiv");
        </script>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <P align="center">Multi-Series Column 2D chart comparing global export index. Click on an item in legend to show/hide the data series.</P>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="qua-button-holder">
            <a class="qua qua-button view-chart-data" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>View XML</span></a>
            <a class="qua qua-button view-chart-data" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>View JSON</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="show-code-block">
             <div class="show-code-close-btn"><a class="qua qua-button" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Close</span></a></div>
             <pre class="prettyprint"></pre>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

E esse é meu XML data (Dados do gráfico e demais variaveis de layout).

```
<chart showBorder='0' formatNumberScale='0' decimals='1' showLegend='1' decimalSeparator=',' thousandSeparator='.' caption='QTD. DE O.S./TEMPO (JUL - 11)' 
vDivLineColor='FFFFFF' numDivlines='5' showLabels='1' bgColor='FFFFFF' showValues='1' showYAxisValues='1' yAxisName='Quantidade de O.S.' showPlotBorder='0' 
canvasbgAlpha='0' canvasBorderAlpha='0' useRoundEdges='0' plotGradientColor='' placeValuesInside='0' yAxisMaxValue='600' legendNumColumns='3' showAlternateHGridColor='0' 
divLineIsDashed='1' divLineDashLen='1' divLineDashGap='2' plotfillalpha='95' >

    <categories>
        <category label='48H'/> 
        <category label='72H' /> 
        <category label='96H'/> 
        <category label='125H' /> 
        <category label='240H' /> 
        <category label='240H' /> 
    </categories>

    <dataset seriesname='NO PRAZO' color='#374092' showValues='0'> 
        <set value='852' displayValue='852' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='488' displayValue='488' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
    </dataset>

    <dataset seriesname='FORA DO PRAZO' color='#FF0000' showValues='0'> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
        <set value='0' displayValue='0' showValue='1'/> 
    </dataset>

    <styles> 
        <definition> 
            <style name='myCaption' type='font' font='Verdana' size='14' color='000000' bold='1'/> 
            <style name='myDataLabels' type='font' size='10' color='000000' bold='0'/> 
            <style name='myDataValues' type='font' color='000000' bold='1'/>
        </definition> 
        <application> 
            <apply toObject='Caption' styles='myCaption' /> 
            <apply toObject='DataLabels' styles='myDataLabels' /> 
            <apply toObject='DataValues' styles='myDataValues' />
        </application> 
    </styles> 
</chart>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Pensou já em abrir o codigo do js e modificá-lo?

Comment: Cara, dei uma olhada no JS fusionCharts, mas nao achei nada que possa estar realizando essa ação de mudar o caption.

Comment: Achei um novo detalhe. Rodando a aplicação no google chrome o problema nao aconteceu, mas no IE 11 aconteceu. Meu projeto é voltado para IE, nao posso utilizar o chrome. Isso pode ser algum bug de javascript?